# Gmail Chat folder in Thunderbird

Tags: gmail, chat, thunderbird

I just configured my gmail account in Thunderbird (Ubuntu) but I do not find "Chat" folder in it.
How do I get that chat folder in Thunderbird?

Comment: are you talking about google chat?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Gmail's web interface.
2. Go into settings (in the gear icon on the right).
3. Click on the Labels tab on top.
4. Check the checkbox that says "Show in IMAP" for the Chats label.
5. Refresh/restart Thunderbird.
6. Done!

Note: In some cases, you may need to follow the additional steps given below:

1. Right click on your email id in Thunderbird.
2. Click on Subscribe
3. Go to [GMail] and make sure that the checkbox for Chats is selected.

Warning: I can only read old chats in Thunderbird. New chats don't seem to show up. Seems like the IMAP folder acts like it's read-only. I can read the new chats in the web interface, nevertheless.